# Resizing Jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to reduce jumbotron's height not with pixels but percentage of something (ex. div's height, windows height). What is the best way to do it appropriate with different window sizes and responsive design.

Here is my code:

```
<!-- START PAGE CONTENT WRAPPER -->
    <div class="page-content-wrapper">
        <!-- START PAGE CONTENT -->
        <div class="content">
            <div class="social-wrapper">
                <div class="social " data-pages="social">
                    <!-- START JUMBOTRON -->
                    <div class="jumbotron" data-pages="parallax" data-social="cover">
                        <div class="cover-photo">
                            <img alt="Cover photo" src="assets/img/social/cover.png" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="container-fluid container-fixed-lg sm-p-l-20 sm-p-r-20">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <div class="pull-bottom bottom-left m-b-40">
                                    <h5 class="text-white no-margin">Team Members</h5>
                                    <h1 class="text-white no-margin"><span class="semi-bold">Lemp</span> Team</h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <!-- END JUMBOTRON -->
        </div>
        <!-- END PAGE CONTENT -->
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can simply overwrite the padding from `.jumbotron` . By default bootstrap has `padding-top: 48px;padding-bottom: 48px;` for jumbotron.

Comment: it doesn't work pal i've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the jumbotron maintain aspect ratio.

Check [Sean Dempsey](http://codepen.io/seanseansean/pen/NPwLxg) fiddle.

Just modify

```
<div class="box sixteen-nine">
<div class="content">
  <span>16:9</span>
</div>
```

to your jumbotron

You can see Chris Coyer [full explanation](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/)